# Texture getting stretched across faces of a cuboid in Open Inventor

Tags: texture-mapping, openinventor, coin3d

I am trying to write a little script to apply texture to rectangular cuboids. To accomplish this, I run through the scenegraph, and wherever I find the SoIndexedFaceSet Nodes, I insert a SoTexture2 Node before that. I put my image file in the SoTexture2 Node. The problem I am facing is that the texture is applied correctly to 2 of the faces(say face1 and face2), in the Y-Z plane, but for the other 4 planes, it just stretches the texture at the boundaries of the two faces(1 and 2).

It looks something like this. [image: Texture Stretching]

The front is how it should look, but as you can see, on the other two faces, it just extrapolates the corner values of the front face. Any ideas why this is happening and any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, assuming that you did not specify texture coordinates for your SoIndexedFaceSet, that is exactly the expected behavior.

If Open Inventor sees that you have applied a texture image to a geometry and did not specify texture coordinates, it will automatically compute some texture coordinates. Of course it's not possible to guess how you wanted the texture to be applied.  So it computes the bounding box then computes texture coordinates that stretch the texture across the largest extent of the geometry (XY, YZ or XZ).  If the geometry is a cuboid you can see the effect clearly as in your image.  This behavior can be useful, especially as a quick approximation.

What you need to make this work the way you want, is to explicitly assign texture coordinates to the geometry such that the texture is mapped separately to each face. In Open Inventor you can actually still share the vertices between faces because you are allowed to specify different vertex indices and texture coordinate indices (of course this is only more convenient for the application because OpenGL doesn't support this and Open Inventor has to re-shuffle the data internally).  If you applied the same texture to an SoCube node you would see that the texture is mapped separately to each face as expected.  That's because SoCube defines texture coordinates for each face.